# git ignore deletes my_database.yml file from Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I am a noob, using a YAML file to store actual database entries (not a config file) for a basic Sinatra app on Heroku.

I found that 'git push heroku' pushed my local test database file 'my_database.yml' to the live version and overwrote the live version.

I therefore tried adding the my_database.yml to my gitignore file and 'git rm --cached my_database.yml'. I expected this to ignore my local my_database.yml file and just push everything else to Heroku, leaving the live database on Heroku intact. What actually happens is that the live database gets deleted.

How should I go about preventing the live database being deleted, or am I missing some concepts somewhere of how to work with dev and live database files with git and Heroku?

Thanks, 
Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku's [filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#isolation-and-security), so using it for long-term file storage isn't a very good idea:

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted. For example, this occurs any time a dyno is replaced due to application deployment and approximately once a day as part of normal dyno management.

The recommended best-practice for storage of unversioned files is to [use something like Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3):

> [AWS Simple Storage Service](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), e.g. S3, is a “highly durable and available store” and can be used to reliably store application content such as media files, static assets and user uploads. It allows you to offload your entire storage infrastructure and offers better scalability, reliability, and speed than just storing files on the filesystem.
>
> AWS S3, or similar storage services, are important when architecting applications for scale and are a perfect complement to Heroku’s [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#isolation-and-security).

In this case I recommend migrating your YAML "database" file to a real database like PostgreSQL. Heroku provides its own [PostgreSQL service](https://www.heroku.com/postgres), or you could use something like [Amazon RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/).

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I'll read up on that. I am aware the next step in my learning is to use a 'proper' database, but haven't got that far. I guess that's the next step.